Travel to Mexico from India, do I need to pay a fee?
I want to travel to Mexico. I have a valid single entry visa for Schengen. Do I need for any visa? Do I need to pay any kind of fee?

You would need to have a multiple-entry Schengen visa to be visa-exempt in Mexico.
From Timatic via Emirates:

Visa
Visa required.
Visa Exemptions

Passengers with a multiple-entry visa issued by Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 180 days.

Exception:

Passengers with a multiple-entry visa issued by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 180 days.

Passengers with a multiple-entry visa issued by the USA for a maximum stay of 180 days. Information: This does not apply when the visa has been extended.


Additional Information:
A Mexican visa in an expired passport is accepted if the passenger also has a valid passport.
Warning:
Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.
Visa issued by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State must be multiple entry. Passengers with this visa are allowed to stay for a maximum stay of 180 days.

(emphasis added)
So you need a separate visa for Mexico.
